# Random native crash in my app that keeps happening on my Nexus 5X

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-canvas, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I keep getting the following native crash at random times, with my own app on Nexus 5X, without a slight clue where is it coming from or how can I fix it.

The app force closes when it happens.

```
2018-12-22 19:12:31.210 426-459/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Toast#0] connect: BufferQueue has been abandoned
2018-12-22 19:12:31.210 24650-24843/com.xyz E/libEGL: eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect (win=0x79ed07e010) failed (0xffffffed) (already connected to another API?)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.210 24650-24843/com.xyz E/libEGL: eglCreateWindowSurface:693 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.211 24650-24843/com.xyz A/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0x79ed07e010, eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC
2018-12-22 19:12:31.657 26160-24843/? A/google-breakpad: Microdump skipped (uninteresting)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.688 24650-24843/com.xyz A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24843 (RenderThread), pid 24650 (com.xyz)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:8.1.0/OPM7.181105.004/5038062:user/release-keys'
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'rev_1.0'
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: pid: 24650, tid: 24843, name: RenderThread  >>> com.xyz <<<
2018-12-22 19:12:31.840 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0x79ed07e010, eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC'
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000610b  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   0000000010000000  x10  00000079e38abc80  x11  0000000000000001
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x12  00000079e38abda0  x13  ffffffffffffffff  x14  ff00000000000000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000005557dddfa8  x17  0000007a882094b8  x18  00000000000001e8  x19  000000000000604a
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x20  000000000000610b  x21  0000000000000083  x22  00000079e38ac588  x23  0000007a87afc0dc
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007a87afc050  x25  00000079e38ac308  x26  00000079e38ac308  x27  00000079e38ac350
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     x28  00000079e38ac300  x29  00000079e38abcc0  x30  0000007a881be6ec
2018-12-22 19:12:31.847 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     sp   00000079e38abc80  pc   0000007a881be714  pstate 0000000060000000
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001d714  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+120)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000007f08  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000006c2a0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::createSurface(ANativeWindow*, bool)+316)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000006a018  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::OpenGLPipeline::setSurface(android::Surface*, android::uirenderer::renderthread::SwapBehavior, android::uirenderer::renderthread::ColorMode)+76)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000066d98  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::setSurface(android::Surface*)+144)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000006f598  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_initialize(android::uirenderer::renderthread::initializeArgs*)+16)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000007189c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+24)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000000729f8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+336)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000011478  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000000a986c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000000067d0c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
2018-12-22 19:12:31.895 26168-26168/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000001eba4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

It's happening even in the background when my app is not displaying anything or hasn't been used for a while.

No clue how to proceed with this and couldn't find info so far.

Comment: Do you have any native code? Do you use native libraries? Any chance those libraries are using [2 different c++ STL](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#one_stl_per_app) ? Are you using opengl in your app?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. No, no, no and no

Comment: Not even textureview or surfaceview?

Comment: @DmitriiZ nope.

Comment: @SirKnigget, Have you understand what is the reason?